# Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/sites/b/domain.com/app/views/viewbuild.blade.php)

Tags: php, exception, laravel, laravel-4

trying to move my site to my live host and cant figure this error out. I have been updating all table and column names etc but cant get my head around this error. Doesnt give much information (to me).

The complete error is:

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/sites/b/domain.com/app/views/viewbuild.blade.php)

Open: /var/sites/b/domain.com/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Engines/PhpEngine.php
    // an exception is thrown. This prevents any partial views from leaking.
    try
    {
        include $__path;
    }
    catch (\Exception $e)
    {
        $this->handleViewException($e, $obLevel);
    }
```

The route for this URL is so:

```
Route::get('viewbuild/{build_id?}/{build_title?}', function($build_id = null, $build_title = null)
{
  $build = Blog::find($build_id);
  if (!is_null($build)) {
    return View::make('viewbuild', compact('build'));
  } else {
    return "Build does not exist";
  }
});
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you see if you add dd($build) after you retrieve $build? Also, I assume you are using Laravel 4.2?

Comment: fixed the error, a commented out PHP line was somehow causing the issue.